# EXCERCISE8.5 py4e got desired output but mismatch error

Tags: python-3.x

```
filename=input("Enter the filename:")

fh = open(filename,'r')
count = 0

for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From:"):
        continue
    count += 1
    words=line.split()
    print(words[1])
    
print("There were",count,"lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

[this is file link from where data is taken](http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)

[MISMATCH ERROR I GOT DESIRED OUTPUT WHAT IS THE PROBLEM??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkFwK.png)

Comment: Please provide the input and the expected output (as text, not image).

Answer (score 0):

You might be having text formatting issues. That's why the **Mismatch**

Kindly check both the outputs for any differences (like blank spaces, new lines etc.,).

Comment: all things are same bur after checking last o/p mismatch is showing in new line after that i dont why one apce is getting add up after displaying o/p i tried striping whitespace but didnt worked

Comment: @UddeshyaKumar Replace the last line in your code with this statement and see. ```print("There were",count,"lines in the file with From as the first word", end='')```.

Comment: There were 27 lines in the file with From as the first word ← Missing output

Comment: when i added end=' ' its showing missing o/p

Comment: @UddeshyaKumar Please add ```end=''```(Just single quotes without space) and NOT ```end=' '```(Single quotes with space) and check.

Comment: i checked both when i used space its showing mismatch and without space and single quotes its missing o/p